# CCK counterpart for user's profiles?

Tags: 7, entities, users

Im looking for a module that allow to add fields to users profiles, with the same functionality and flexibility of CCK for nodes; I've actually activated the profile module, but the fields type doesnt fit my needs.

For example, i need to have a node reference field on my users (for nodes that they belongs to - follow), but in general, profile's fields doesnt allow multiple values at all..

I've tryed [content profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module, i guess will be my last choice, i dont like to have the user profile and the profile node as two separate entities.. and look a bit overlìkill for me.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Drupal 6, these are the only two options I know of, either use content_profile and use aditional nodes or stick with what profile.module can do.

In Drupal 7 however, users are fieldable, which means that you can attach any field that you can attach to nodes too. Additionally, there is the http://drupal.org/project/profile2 project, which provides something similar to content_profile. However, profiles are in that case not nodes but a custom entity.

Comment: Well, content_profile is not my best bet for my case, but with few hooks i've been able to fit my needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Advanced Profile kit](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_profile) module..

Answer (score 0):

you can go "yourpage.com"/admin/config/people/accounts/fields and create some custom field for your profile and then go to "yourpage.com"/admin/config/people/accounts/display to custumise how it looks in drupal 7 ,also use http://drupal.org/project/pux to setup how it will look like.

in drupal 7 you can use the number of values that you want (http://drupal.org/node/1312562 just to illustrate ) for each field when you edit the field in manage fields tab. also if you wanna put together some fields use field collection http://drupal.org/project/field_collection.
here you can find the video tutorial how it works. http://droplabs.net/video/field-collection-in-drupal-7.